# Create a vertical stack of three individual buttons

Tags: css, woocommerce, css-selectors

I have the following block of code used on my site, with individual class name for each button.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'additional_simple_add_to_cart_10', 20 );
function additional_simple_add_to_cart_10() {
    global $product;

// Only for variable product type 
    $href = '?add-to-cart=' . esc_attr( $product->get_id() ) . '&quantity=10';
$class = 'ingle_add_to_cart_button-10 button alt';
$style = 'display: inline-block; margin-top: 12px;';
$button_text = __( "10 Tickets", "woocommerce" );

// Output
echo '<br><a rel="no-follow" href="'.$href.'" class="'.$class.'" style="'.$style.'">'.$button_text.'</a>';

}
```

Each button currently sits next to each other inline. I'm not too great with css, my three buttons are named below. How can I get them in a vertical group on top of each other? Or is this possible if they all share the same name?

> `ingle_add_to_cart_button-10 button alt`
>   `ingle_add_to_cart_button-5 button alt`
>   `ingle_add_to_cart_button-1 button alt`

Comment: If you are going to ask a CSS question about styling HTML then it's a good idea to show the HTML and CSS and not whatever that block of code is you did show. [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your three buttons in a div container. In your CSS add:

```
display: flex; flex-direction: column
```

If you don't want to add a container you can hack your way through by setting each button width to

```
width: 100vw;
```